# GridView Click not working

Tags: android, gridview

I have the following layout . What I'm trying to achieve is 7 horizontal scrollablelayouts with an "ImageView" and a gridview in each. When I click on each of the 7 gridviews I'm hoping to start another activity.

Problem is setting onClickListener on each of the 7 gridView is not working , the OnItemClickListener is never called. the click is not registering apparently. I'm not sure what is going wrong. I saw a few posts which said that click is going to some other child item-- ?? i'm not sure which child item. Worst case I might be able to register a click on the 7  imageViews and take an according action. At the moment I'm trying it out when the gridview is empty. even when its showing images i want a click to happen only on the gridView and not on any of its individual contents.

```
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
     >
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
       <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="80dp"
         android:src="@drawable/mon"

          android:scaleType="centerInside"
          android:background="@android:color/white"
          android:cropToPadding="true"
          />
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview_mon"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
     >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
  <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="80dp"
         android:src="@drawable/tue"

          android:scaleType="centerInside"
          android:background="@android:color/white"
          android:cropToPadding="true"
          />

<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview_tue"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
  <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="80dp"
         android:src="@drawable/wed"

          android:scaleType="centerInside"
          android:background="@android:color/white"
          android:cropToPadding="true"
          />

<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview_wed"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
     >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
  <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="80dp"
         android:src="@drawable/thu"

          android:scaleType="centerInside"
          android:background="@android:color/white"
          android:cropToPadding="true"
          />

<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview_thu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
     >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
  <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="80dp"
         android:src="@drawable/fri"

          android:scaleType="centerInside"
          android:background="@android:color/white"
          android:cropToPadding="true"
          />

<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview_fri"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
     >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
  <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="80dp"
         android:src="@drawable/sat"

          android:scaleType="centerInside"
          android:background="@android:color/white"
          android:cropToPadding="true"
          />

<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview_sat"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
  <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="80dp"
         android:src="@drawable/sun"

          android:scaleType="centerInside"
          android:background="@android:color/white"
          android:cropToPadding="true"
          />

<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview_sun"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1"
/>

         </LinearLayout>
         </HorizontalScrollView>    
         </LinearLayout>   

</ScrollView>
```

One of the click listener setting given below

```
mMonView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridview_mon);
try {
    setupAdapter(mMonView, mWeekPlanner.getDayList(WeekPlanner.MON));
} catch (InvalidClothesWeekPlannerException e) {
    setupAdapter(mMonView, null);
}
mMonView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> gridView, View view,
            int pos, long id) {
        // Clothes item
        // =mWeekPlanner.getDayList(WeekPlanner.MON).get(pos);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "YAY gridview clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        Intent intent =new Intent(getActivity(),WeekPagerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(WeekPlannerFragment.EXTRA_DAY, WeekPlanner.MON);
        startActivity(intent); 


    }
});
```

Comment: can you show your code where you call onitemclicklistener..

Comment: one of them pasted below

Comment: where..here you only paste the layout xml file. i want the java code i.e onitemclicklistener..

Comment: what you want.. put show() in toast ,,,

Comment: is this the adapter class..

Comment: this bit is inside the fragment displaying this view ,the adapter is an inner class. At the moment ive put a click listener on the imageview next to the gridview as well and am getting the desired behaviour. Do you think the click listener on the gridView is not working because there are no elements in it?

Comment: just change your context first from getActivity to superclass.this and add a show() to toast. and let me know what happens....

Comment: ignore the toast part

Comment: the click on gridview works when there are items in it not otherwise:P plus the horizontal scrollview works not