# how to achieve spacing multiple gridlayout view

Tags: android, android-layout

hi i have this layout pasted below in which i have 7 gridlayouts like

imgView1 GridLayout1
imgView2 GridLayout2
....
imgView7 GridLayout7

I have several problems in this layout as mentioned in "[GridView Click not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581414/gridview-click-not-working)" which i have chosen to ignore.

For the time being my problem is i want to achieve even spacing between each of these 7 entries. Currently the entries (linear layout horizontal consisting of imgView and Gridlayout) are closely spaced when there are no entries in the gridlayout. for eg i have entries in gridlayout 1 & 2 and they have sufficient space between each horizontal layers but the next 5 layers are huddled together separated only by the   android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" in the horizontalscrollview. what would be the best way to get even  spacing irrespective of gridlayout having entries or not.

i also tried giving a specific layout_height to the imageView (but this had the jarring effect of the grid layout and the corresponding imageview not being horizontally aligned)

Really appreciate any suggestions. Im also wondering if i should replace the horizontalscrollview with a relativelayout because im not getting any scrolling.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     >
    <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
     >
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     >
       <ImageView
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/imageview_mon"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/mon"
          android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
          android:gravity="top"
          android:scaleType="centerInside"
          android:cropToPadding="true"
          />
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview_mon"
    android:layout_width="0dip" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" 
     >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
  <ImageView
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/imageview_tue"
          android:gravity="top"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/tue"

          android:scaleType="centerInside"
          android:cropToPadding="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
          />

<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview_tue"
    android:layout_width="0dip" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
  <ImageView
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/imageview_wed"
          android:gravity="top"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/wed"

          android:scaleType="centerInside"
          android:cropToPadding="true"
           android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
          />

<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview_wed"
    android:layout_width="0dip" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
     >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
  <ImageView
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/imageview_thu"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/thu"
          android:gravity="top"  
          android:scaleType="centerInside"
          android:cropToPadding="true"
           android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
          />

<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview_thu"
    android:layout_width="0dip" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
     >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
  <ImageView
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/imageview_fri"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/fri"
          android:gravity="top"
          android:scaleType="centerInside"
          android:cropToPadding="true"
           android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
          />

<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview_fri"
    android:layout_width="0dip" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
     >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
  <ImageView
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/imageview_sat"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/sat"
          android:gravity="top"
          android:scaleType="centerInside"
          android:cropToPadding="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
          />

<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview_sat"
    android:layout_width="0dip" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
  <ImageView
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/imageview_sun"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/sun"
          android:gravity="top"  
          android:scaleType="centerInside"
          android:cropToPadding="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
          />

<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview_sun"
    android:layout_width="0dip" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1"
/>

         </LinearLayout>
         </HorizontalScrollView>    
         </LinearLayout>   

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: it is not a better practice to have a scrollable inside another scrollable view

Comment: yeah i saw that warning, i just chose to ignore it , i should probably get rid of those grid layouts and replace with two imageviews, im anyway not getting anything more from it at the moment(its clickable so i get all the piccys in a dedicated per day view). what is the bestway to get a single line gridview? gallery is deprecated isnt it

Comment: i'm trying to substitute the scrollview+gridview with https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview. its not as easy to use as i would have liked it to be